# Get a sample of each doctype from Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am working with a Couchbase bucket where all documents are saved with a `DocType` attribute identifying what type of data is contained.  I want to perform a query that will give me a single result from each `DocType`, to use as a sample of all document types.

I can get each DocType using `SELECT DISTINCT(DocType) FROM some-database`.  And I can get a sample by doing `SELECT * FROM some-database WHERE DocType='User' LIMIT 1`.  But I don't know how to combine these things to make a single query return a single example from each matching DocType.

Comment: Depending on what your intentions are, you may want to look into the `INFER` statement as well - https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/infer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GROUP query.

```
SELECT MAX(d).*
FROM default AS d
WHERE d.DocType IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY d.DocType;
```

OR
    First get one document key for different DocType using covered index and then
    get those documents.

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON default(DocType);

SELECT d1.* 
FROM default d1 USE KEYS (
         SELECT RAW MAX(META(d).id)
         FROM default AS d
         WHERE d.DocType IS NOT NULL
         GROUP BY d.DocType);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect!